# Proper drawing of arc of a circle based on time

Tags: android, math, canvas, wear-os

HoursPassed : 0 - 23
MinsPassed : 0 - 59

I want to calculate degrees(x) of an arc that's based on the time passed

```
p = timePassed (hoursPassed * 60 + minutesPassed)

p / 24 * 60 = x / 360
360p / 24 * 60 = x
36p / 24 * 6 = x
6p / 24 = x
p / 4 = x
```

Thus :

```
int minsPassed = mTime.minute;
int hoursPassed = mTime.hour;


float timePassed = minsPassed + hoursPassed * 60;

float degs = timePassed / 4;
```

Lets try to draw the arc : im using the new wearable API , so I can use the method

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds)
```

It provides me with a cancas object and a bounds object:

Lets try to draw the arc:

```
canvas.drawArc(new RectF(bounds) , 0 , degsForBigCircle , false , aPaintObject);
```

This is what I end up with:

[image: Picture]

Nevermind the time being drawn too, I want the light blue drawing to be an arc of the circle, instead of a sector.

You can find the whole project on [Github](https://github.com/Zarkopafilis/ZCycle).

Comment: @cimbali A wedge is drawn instead of an arc. Plus I want it to start from middle-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, the problem is in the options of `aPaintObject` : you have to look at [`Paint.Style`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.Style.html).

So setting the paint style to only stroke and not fill, before drawing, your code becomes :

```
aPaintObject.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
canvas.drawArc(new RectF(bounds) , 0 , degsForBigCircle , false , aPaintObject);
```